# What does it mean to say that "6 tons of dark energy would be found within the radius of Pluto's orbit"?

Tags: space, dark-energy

What does it mean to say that "6 tons of dark energy would be found within the radius of Pluto's orbit"?

- Does it mean that the dark energy is orbiting the solar system?
- Or does it mean a flow of dark energy through a sphere?
- Or does it refers to an energy in a particular system of inertia in
  the solar system?

Or what?

> Again on a mass–energy equivalence basis, the density of dark energy
>   (6.91 × 10−27 kg/m3) is very low: in the solar system, it is estimated
>   only 6 tons of dark energy would be found within the radius of Pluto's
>   orbit. However, it comes to dominate the mass–energy of the universe
>   because it is uniform across space. Wikipedia/Dark energy

Comment: They used $E=mc^2$ to convert energy density into mass density, or so it seems. I could not guess why they did it since giving a mass of dark energy is both confusing and misleading. Best to ignore the 6 tons thing

Comment: What do you mean by "system of inertia?"

Comment: Ben Crowell: some geometrical frame with no movement relative the sun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't really know what dark energy is, but the default description is that it's not really dynamical. It can't flow or orbit. It's just a fixed built-in energy that is possessed by every cubic centimeter of space.

On a more technical level, the simplest way to accomodate dark energy in the Einstein field equations is by adding a cosmological constant term. Naive attempts to make it variable rather than constant cause the stress-energy tensor to have a nonvanishing divergence, which makes GR not self-consistent.